# What does it mean to start a server in your own computer and access the application through you computer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I understand that the rails s command starts a server and you can access your Rails application because of this command.

However, don't you usually have to connect to some other server outside of one's computer?

Comment: off course, starting a server on your machine is only for proofing your website! that's why you have 3 different environments setups (test, development, production). Under development environments your database is a local database, and starting the server on your machine will access that very database. Independently of the same website hosted remotely which may have a differently populated database (actual users data ..). All this is done not to interfere with real data on the web.

Comment: So basically: you develop your website under development environment. You need to have a database server installed on your computer (postgres ..) and your environment config file will be set up to connect to this database. Then when you do `rails s` your local application on `localhost:3000` will connect to that very database (on your computer). No one except you can see this. Then when your website is finished. You upload the Rails app remotely and you don't have to do a `Rails s`, Heroku or other service provider will do that for you, on their own servers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why that? A server is just a "computer" and it can be your one. One difference is that you make HTTP request in your local network (from the browser to the server on your machine). While in a request to a real server the request also starts from your browser but reach a server elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

What is probably being referred to is the ability to start a Virtual Machine or a VM on your computer, or possibly the server being referred to is an application which acts a server daemon on your computer and will respond to packets received over a specific port, like 80/443 with the nginx web server.

It is a good idea to develop inside of a VM if that was the case, it provides a custom environment that is similar to a production setting and reduces conflicts between projects.